# Classifying text based on Keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having document like the following format and I want to categorize it with python, for example

```
Outline: 
1. Lorem Ipsum 
2. Lorem Ipsum 

Preface: 
This is sample generated words of the documents
```

Those has to be categorized into arrays, for example

```
[Outline: 1. Lorem Ipsum 2. Lorem Ipsum, Preface: This is sample generated words of the documents ]
```

Or stored in different variable, for example

```
outline = segment_by_word("outline")
preface = segment_by_word("preface")

print(preface )  #This is sample generated words of the documents
```

Comment: Will there always be an outline before the Preface?

Comment: @DanielButler Nope, the sequence might vary, that is why i'm trying to extract it by keyword "Outline" or "Preface"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that there are only two categories `Ouline` and `Preface`. The code below adds the lines to a list as a tuple with the line # then the line information

```
lines_by_category = {'Outline': [], 'Preface': []}
category = None
count = 0

for line in lines:  # Assuming you know how to get to the point of reading lines
    if line.find(r'Outline:'):
        category = 'Outline'
    elif line.find(r'Preface:'):
        category = 'Preface'
    category_list = lines_by_category[category]
    category_list.append((count, line))  # Updates the original list because it is pointing to the same one
```